# How to change material to another material at specified keyframe

Tags: animation, materials

Is there any way I could have the material be a certain texture and then at keyframe 20 it changes to a different texture?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a *Mix RGB* node, plug one texture into the first input and the other into the second input. Then set keyframes for the Mix factor, change it from 0 (first texture) to 1 (second texture). For an instant change insert a keyframe for 0 at frame 19 and another for 1 at frame 20. If you set the 0 at an earlier frame you can make a smooth transition between those textures.

EDIT: Since Alexis mentioned the *Mix Shader* node in his comment, here something just for completion: If you really meant *materials* like in the title instead of *textures*, you can of course create two completely different node setups in one material. And just before the *Material Output* node you insert a *Mix Shader* node, connect those two different setups each in one socket and keyframe the *Fac* value in the *Mix Shader* node.

Comment: I suspect you mean a *Mix Shader* node, not a Mix RGB node.

Comment: No... if the textures are images you can use a _Mix RGB_ and plug the output into a color slot of a Diffuse, Principled BSDF, Emission Shader... whatever.

Comment: Ah, you’re right—I didn’t read the question body carefully enough and was just going off the title.